# How to check if a multiple variable are empty?

Tags: vb.net

I know how to check if variable is empty or not, but what I'm trying to do is display a message on the empty variable, for example:

```
    Dim server_name = TextBox1.Text
    Dim username = TextBox2.Text
    Dim password = TextBox3.Text
    Dim database = TextBox4.Text

    If server_name.Length > 0 And username.Length > 0 And password.Length > 0 And database.Length > 0 Then

    End If
```

How you can see I've a multiple condition, so if server_name is empty I want display a message

> Server name field isn't filled correctly

It's possible do this without an else if?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an `If...` even if you don't like it. However, if you want something "more elegant" you could use a collection and `Linq`:

```
Dim allFields = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) From {
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Server name", server_name),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("User name", username),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Password", password),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)("Database", database)
}

Dim invalids = From kv In allFields
               Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value) 

For Each invalid In invalids
    Console.WriteLine("{0} field isn't filled correctly", invalid.Key)
Next
```

---

> Just another question, it's possible set the foreground color red to
>   the empty field in the foreach?

Yes, then you need to store the `TextBox` instead of only it's `Text` as `Value`. Then you can set the color of the `TextBox` in the loop:

```
Dim allFields As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, TextBox)) From {
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, TextBox)("Server name", TextBox1),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, TextBox)("User name", TextBox2),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, TextBox)("Password", TextBox3),
    New KeyValuePair(Of String, TextBox)("Database", TextBox4)
}

Dim invalids = From kv In allFields
               Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value.Text) 

For Each invalid In invalids
    Console.WriteLine("{0} field isn't filled correctly", invalid.Key)
    invalid.Value.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
Next
```

Note that this has another advantage: you could even declare this list as a field in your class(form). So you only need to declare and initialize it once. If you execute the LINQ query at the `For Each` it will automatically evaluate it with the current values in the textboxes, not the initial ones when the list was initialized. Side-note: you should use more meaningful names like `TxtPassword` instead of `TextBox3`.

Comment: @Dillinger: that's a [LINQ query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384667.aspx). You need to add `Imports System.Linq`, either to the file or project wide(preferably).

Comment: Just another question, it's possible set the foreground color red to the empty field in the foreach?

Comment: @Dillinger: yes, then you need to store the `TextBox` instead of only it's `Text` as value. Then you can set the color of the `TextBox` in the loop with: `invalid.Value.ForeColor = Color.Red`. Of course you also have to change the query slightly: `... Where String.IsNullOrEmpty(kv.Value.Text) `

Comment: Okay could you update the answer please? Thanks and have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, I'll give you an example:

```
Dim s As String() = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text}
If String.Join("", s).Length > 0 Then
    ' program logic
End If
```

Effectively, you are creating an array of strings and then you join them and check the final string's length.